# Getting Port 8080 was already in use error from docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I've got 4 Spring Boot microservices that I'm trying to run with docker-compose.  When I start them with `docker-compose up` I get an error saying that port 8080 is already in use:

```
product_1            | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
product_1            | ***************************
product_1            | 
product_1            | Description:
product_1            | 
product_1            | Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.
product_1            | 
product_1            | Action:
product_1            | 
product_1            | Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I know the Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml are correct because I've copied them from a working version of the code.  My Dockerfiles are all like this:

```
FROM openjdk:12.0.2

EXPOSE 8080

ADD ./target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  product:
    build: microservices/product-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  recommendation:
    build: microservices/recommendation-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  review:
    build: microservices/review-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  product-composite:
    build: microservices/product-composite-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker

  # $ mongo
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6.9
    mem_limit: 350m
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --smallfiles

  # $ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -p
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    mem_limit: 350m
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=review-db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-uuser", "-ppwd", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
```

All the services run on server.port 8080.

I've checked and before launching `docker-compose up` there is nothing running on port 8080.

This example is from the new book ***Hands-On Microservices with
Spring Boot and Spring Cloud*** by Magnus Larsson.  His example code works, and I've copied the Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml from his code so they must be correct.  It's my code that I've written while reading the book that has this problem, but all the application.yml, Dockerfile, and docker-compose.yml files are the same as the working code.

Where should I look for the cause of this problem?

**Update:**  I commented out all other services except for the product-service and mongodb.  Docker compose is trying to start the product-service twice:

```
product_1  | 2019-10-03 12:59:26.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] e.e.m.c.p.ProductServiceApplication      : Starting ProductServiceApplication v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on 902ca18da442 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)

product_1  | 2019-10-03 12:59:29.397  INFO 1 --- [           main] e.e.m.c.p.ProductServiceApplication      : Starting ProductServiceApplication v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on 902ca18da442 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
```

I've verified that this doesn't happen with other services so now the question is why is docker-compose trying to start the product-service twice.

Comment: from the error report itseld thats sounds more like an internal problem of the first `product` service (reported by the java app unable to bind to 8080 inside the `product` container). To investigate that you can use a `netstat` or any other way of checking if there may be anything listening inside `product` service just before starting `app.jar`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my problem was that my product-service was calling SpringApplication.run() twice.  So it was not related to docker-compose.  I'll leave this post up in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 1):

use command prompt

`netstat -ano | findstr 8080` - for finding the PID for the service that used the port 
ts`kill "PID"` - to kill the service (don't use the quote tag)

then try to re-run it. hopeful it could help you

Comment: There's nothing running on 8080 before I run `docker-compose up`. I've already checked that.